# How can I maintain persist a Cloud Functions connection using ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, network-programming, google-cloud-functions

```
const http = require('http');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const agent = new http.Agent({keepAlive: true});

exports.function = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    req = http.request({
        host: '',
        port: 80,
        path: '',
        method: 'GET',
        agent: agent,
    }, res => {
        let rawData = '';
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', chunk => { rawData += chunk; });
        res.on('end', () => {
            response.status(200).send(`Data: ${rawData}`);
        });
    });
    req.on('error', e => {
        response.status(500).send(`Error: ${e.message}`);
    });
    req.end();
});
```

This is the code from [Optimizing networking using Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/networking). How can I update it to use expressJS.

So from the code I see that the trick is this line `const agent = new http.Agent({keepAlive: true})` and then in the request `agent: agent`.

I tried doing something like

```
const server = express()

server.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.agent = new http.Agent({keepAlive: true})
    next()
})
```

But did't work. HELP!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just put on index.js

```
require('https').globalAgent.keepAlive = true;
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. When posting links to your own content, you **must** disclose that it is yours. If you do not, then it is considered spam. For more information, please see [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).